# how to: dynamic div width according to gallery content

Tags: css, wordpress, dynamic, width, html

http://portfolio.curiouslucious.com/?page_id=8

I'm trying to create a horizontal scrolling gallery (with a edited wordpress theme)
Currently, I have the nextGen Gallery plugin which manages all my images.

Right now, the only way I can get the images to display next to each other and scroll horizontally is to set the gallery width to something massive - 10000px

```
/* ----------- Gallery style -------------*/

.ngg-galleryoverview {
overflow: hidden;
margin-top: 10px;
width:10000px;
overflow: hidden;
clear:both; 
display:inline-block !important;
}

/* ----------- Gallery style -------------*/
```

is there a way I can make the width change dynamically dependent on the number of images?

here is the stylesheet.css code

```
/* Blocks       */
#container { width:1000px; margin:25px 60px; }
#left-box { float:left; width:270px; margin-right:65px; }
#sidebar { float:right; text-align:right; }
#sidebar ul { text-align:right; list-style:none; }
#sidebar h3 { font-size:1em; }
#sidebar small { font-size:0.7em; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
#author_note { font-size:0.85em; width:220px; padding:5px; border:1px solid #CDCDCD; float:right; text-align:right; }
#notes { width:600px; float:left; margin-top:20px; overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden;     height:500px; display:inline-block;}
#notes h1 { font-size:1.6em; font-weight:normal; margin:0; padding:0; }
#logo { float:right; margin-top:30px; }
#navigation { clear:right;float:right; width:270px; text-align:right; }
.copyright { margin-top:40px; color:#999999; } 
.copyright a { color:#666666; text-decoration:underline; }
.copyright .theme { font-size:0.7em; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }    
.copyright .theme a { color:#999; text-decoration:none; }
.pages { margin-top:80px; font-size:1.1em; font-weight:200; }
.pages li { margin-top:5px; font-size:0.9em; }
.categories { margin-top:45px; font-size:0.85em; }
.links { margin-top:45px; font-size:0.85em; }
.navigation { margin-bottom:50px; font-size:0.85em; }
```

I'd prefer to avoid javascript if possible as I know I'm going to have huge issues implementing it. But any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to support IE7, then you can apply...

```
.theContent {
  display: table;
}

.ngg-galleryoverview {
  display: table-row;
  float: none;
}

ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
}
```

Then it will show up as you want to. There will still be some issues, but I'm sure you can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're trying to do is possible with pure CSS. I whipped up a custom jQuery plugin that should work with your code.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/KHT32/4/

I made this so it sets the dimensions dynamically based on the image with the greatest height and the sum of the width of all the images plus the margin-right (so you can add some space between them).

jQuery plugin code...

---

EDIT :: Fixes!

```
#scrollGal {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 15px;
}

#scrollGal img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#scrollGal div {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#notes {
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

EDIT: Remove the "scrollGal" div from your HTML. Replace the JS with the following (the new code will wrap the appropriate div with the scrollGal div)...

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.scrollGal = function() {
        return this.each(function() {

            $(this).wrap('<div id="scrollGal" />');
            $sg = $(this).parent();

            var obj = $(this).find('img');
            var arr = $.makeArray(obj);
            var w = 0, ww = 0, h = 0;
            $.each(arr, function(i, val) {
                w += $(this).width();
                w += (parseInt($(this).css('marginRight')));
                // find greatest width
                var nw = $(this).width();
                if (nw > ww) ww = nw;
                // find greatest height
                var nh = $(this).height();
                if (nh > h) h = nh;
            });
            $sg.width(ww);
            $sg.height(h);
            $sg.children('div').width(w);

        });
    };
})( jQuery );

$('#ngg-gallery-1-8').scrollGal();
```

Comment: Bah! Was hoping to avoid this. Am a coding noob and have no idea which js and css files i should be editing.
I assume the JS should be related to the gallery plugin, and the CSS to the php file that's related to the entry, and I've put the html into the php file but so far... not working.

Comment: I had a feeling so I tried to keep it pretty basic. You can add the CSS to the end of your style.css file. You can create a new file called scrollGal.js and place that in your wp-includes/js directory and put the js from the demo I linked into there (make sure you load scrollGal.js after your page load jquery.js -- look above the <head> tag). As for the html you'll have to put that on the template page and have the gallery code load in between that.

Comment: hrm..it's not quite working. even though it seems like it's loading all the right files... thanks for your patience!http://portfolio.curiouslucious.com/?page_id=8

Comment: Having trouble putting the scrollGal div in right before the ngg-gallery div because ngg-gallery is a plugin that gets called and ends up looking like this when outputted -

    <div class="entry">
<div id="scrollGal">
          <div class="theID"></div>
          <div class="theContent">
<div class="ngg-galleryoverview" id="ngg-gallery-1-8">

Tried to replace the function in the js plugin but doesnt work. The .ngg-galleryoverview tag is in a stylesheet which is part of the plugin (not stylesheet.css) - could be something to do with the separate stylesheet for the gallery plugin?

Comment: Ok, see the latest edits. Basically you can take out the scrollGal div from your HTML and the jQuery will automatically add it in (so update the js file with the new code).

Comment: http://portfolio.curiouslucious.com/?page_id=8

still no go =( refuses to scroll horizontal. is there any more info i could give you to help with the coding? we must be missing something...

and thank you!! you're being very helpful.